# how to merge multiple json files into a single file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Within a directory, I can have several files, taking as an example...

**chunk26.4ec7e9b2.json**

```
{
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css?id=0f487b3ea1da478a47ce"
}
```

**chunk57.9bc6ea1f.json**

```
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js?id=f3eda47538cccd3ab358",
    "/js/empresa.js": "/js/empresa.js?id=2e389af5c75f398c7c97",
    "/js/passwordreset.js": "/js/passwordreset.js?id=2f48c7b9a250fb573381",
    "/js/prelogin.js": "/js/prelogin.js?id=4835300bf9075df04126"
}
```

How is it possible to merge these files, as a valid json file, remembering that I can have N files and their names can be anything but always with the json extension, and this result will be saved in the current directory.

**expected outcome**

```
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js?id=f3eda47538cccd3ab358",
    "/js/empresa.js": "/js/empresa.js?id=2e389af5c75f398c7c97",
    "/js/passwordreset.js": "/js/passwordreset.js?id=2f48c7b9a250fb573381",
    "/js/prelogin.js": "/js/prelogin.js?id=4835300bf9075df04126",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css?id=0f487b3ea1da478a47ce"
}
```

Important note is that the last line must not have a comma.

[image]

As I'm still learning python, I got a part, at least I could see each line

```
import glob;
files=[];

for filename in glob.glob("*.json"):
    print(filename);
    files.append(filename);

print(files);

for filename in files:
    with open(filename, "r") as a_file:
          for line in a_file:
              print(line)
```

... but I really don't know if it is the most functional or practical way to achieve the expected result

Comment: Can you read the json files,merge them and put it in a new json file?

Comment: Yes, but it is not enough to just merge, because in this new file you cannot have two sets of keys, and the last line, it must always not have a comma

Comment: what do you expect to happen if there are repeating keys in the files? Check `json` module. Reading file by file and combine into one dict and then dump into file will not produce comma after the last one.

Comment: Also it looks like you use python3, but your question is tagged `python-2.7` - why?

Comment: because I'm using version 2.7 and I can't change to another version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a small util called [package-json-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-json-merge). This is a nodejs lib, but I think it is worth to mention it here.

Note that the order of files matters when we talk about similar fields

In your case it might be something like this

```
package-json-merge chunk57.9bc6ea1f.json chunk26.4ec7e9b2.json > result.json
```

Comment: Good sugestion! I'm going to test, I didn't know this pak

Comment: Note that this is a nodejs lib though

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

files = ['file1.json', 'file2.json', 'file3.json']
combined_json = {}
for filename in files:
    with open(filename) as f:
        file_json = json.load(f)
    combined_json.update(file_json)
```

Comment: It helped a lot, it only lacked how to save, but I ended up finding it, thanks to your help.... `with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(combined_json, f)
`